# Grouping of subset of multiple Column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, exploratory-data-analysis

Having a data set as below.Here I need to group the subset in column and fill the missing values using mode method.

Need to group the value 'Tom' from name and 'UK' from Country and fill the missing value in value using mode.

| Name | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | USA | 30.0 |
| Tom | UK | 20.0 |
| Tom | UK | NaN |
| nick | USA | 19.0 |
| nick | USA | 18.0 |
| Tom | India | 23.0 |
| nick | USA | 15.0 |
| nick | USA | 20.0 |
| jack | India | NaN |
| Tom | UK | 23.0 |
| Tom | UK | 23.0 |

I tried the code below.

```
np.where((data['Name'] == 'Tom') & (data['Country']=='UK'),data['Value'].fillna(data['Value'].mode()[0]),data['Value'])
```

Comment: What you have works fine... did you forget to assign with with `df['Value'] = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `.eq() .lt() .ge()` etc, to avoid excess `()` everywhere when combining conditions~

Also, since this isn't an `if...else`, we can just use `pd.DataFrame.mask` instead of `np.where`~

I also assumed that you only want the `mode` of the same group~ rather than the whole column. If you want the whole column change `data.loc[mask, 'Value']` to just `data['Value']`

```
mask = (data['Name'].eq('Tom') & 
        data['Country'].eq('UK'))
data['Value'] = data['Value'].mask(mask & data['Value'].isna(), 
                                   data.loc[mask, 'Value'].mode()[0])
```

```
    Name Country  Value
0    Tom     USA   30.0
1    Tom      UK   20.0
2    Tom      UK   23.0
3   nick     USA   19.0
4   nick     USA   18.0
5    Tom   India   23.0
6   nick     USA   15.0
7   nick     USA   20.0
8   jack   India    NaN
9    Tom      UK   23.0
10   Tom      UK   23.0
```

Comment: instead of mode, if i want average- how can i change this code?

Comment: @Jack Just change `.mode()[0]` to `.mean()` The difference is due to the fact that `.mode()` can return multiple values if they match in frequency. Another good option would be `.median()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to go as far as masking the data for the mode you can simply try:

```
data['Value'] = np.where((data['Name'] == 'Tom') & (data['Country']=='UK'),data['Value'].fillna(data['Value'].mode()[0]),data['Value'])
```

Edit:
If you'd like to address only those Null values where the Name is Tom and Country UK, you can add an additional criteria:

```
data['Value'] = np.where((data['Name'] == 'Tom') & (data['Country']=='UK') & (data['Value'].isna()),data['Value'].mode()[0],data['Value'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this has been fixed now.

Comment: @BeRT2me, Is it like this?`data['Value'] = np.where((data['Name'] == 'Tom') & (data['Country']=='UK'),data['Value'].isna(data['Value'].mode()[0]),data['Value'])`.

Comment: @Jack No, it'd be more like I have in my answer. `(data['Name'] == 'Tom') & (data['Country']=='UK') & (data['Value'].isna())...`

Comment: Edited to account for OPs follow up question